# Permission issues about Plex Media Server

Tags: 16.04, permissions, hard-drive, fstab, plex

I have a problem with the Plex Media Player. Plex can not see media files placed inside the external HDD folders. Theoretically it would be a permission problem.  I can not change the permissions.

I followed the instructions in [here](http://nickescobedo.com/640/how-to-fix-plex-media-server-not-recognizing-files-on-separate-hard-drive) but it didn't work. Maybe I made a mistake by changing the fstab file.

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Just now I realize that editing fstab file I can no longer reboot Ubuntu..  Rebooting my PC, when I have to select whic OS to run, I choose Ubuntu e it shows like this https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9LXwSje2n-HTGhKUXVvbk1WanM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: changes to the fstab can be made via a live session (cd/dvd/usb)

Comment: @db429 I am running live session. Just opened fstab file but... what to edit?

Comment: well if you post the content of your fstab, it might be easier to help.

Comment: I find fstab file inside /etc.  Inside: " overlay / overlay r 0 0 "   second line: " tmpfs /tmp tmpfs nosuid, nodev 0 0

Comment: in your live system mount the harddrive  where you installed ubuntu in, then you can find it in /media/(something)/etc/fstab - please edit your question and put the content of the whole file there. thx

Comment: if you followed the above mentioned instructions properly you should have a fstab.old; so you could copy it back  with: `sudo cp /media/(something)/etc/fstab.old /media/(something)/etc/fstab`

Comment: Thanx a lot. Issue just fixed!  How to change your comment in answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, since you followed the instructions (mentioned in your question) you should have a backup of the original fstab named fstab.old.

So let's use a live system to boot and restore this old version.

Inside the live system - let's assume you used the graphical interface to mount the partition, we should find it under `/media/ubuntu/(something)`.

So lets open a terminal with `Ctrl+Alt+t` and then copy back the backed up file with `sudo cp /media/ubuntu/(something)/etc/fstab.old /media/ubuntu/(something)/etc/fstab`

To avoid typing the full address of the mountpoint - especially this `(something)` part - you can use auto-completion via pressing the Tabulator-Key twice.

Hope this helps.